# Apple's still fairly adamant about capping Windows at Safari 5.1.7; what's a decent way to run 6+ anyway?

Tags: windows, installation, safari, emulator

I wrote a little bit of WordPress code that's still in the early stages of development, and somebody ran across a bug with one of the links.  Unfortunately I'm having trouble reproducing the issue, as I'm running Windows, and they were using Safari 6.1.6 on a Mac.  When I try the link in IE, Firefox, Chrome, or even Safari 5.1.7, this problem does not occur.  Something seems to be specific about the fact that they were using 6.1.6 and/or the Mac operating system.

So I've Googled some, and the results that keep coming back are not really helping.  There's no end of links that complain or make an "announcement" about Apple dropping Safari support for Windows, and every download link that comes up (even when searching for Safari 6.1.6 and other stuff like that) just deals with 5.1.7.

If there's some sort of emulator that's a good idea to use, what might it be?  I'd rather follow some advice than to go too far off the deep end on my own when messing with my operating system.  If an emulator's not the correct approach, then is there some sort of way to get a copy of 6.1.6 and manipulate the file or something?  It's been suggested in one spot on this site to simply use Chrome to test for Safari 6+ on Windows, but that's not good enough in this situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy in this case,  aside from running a hackintosh in a vm (which is slightly illegal)  would be to go to an apple store or use a friend's computer. Try to figure out what you want to test beforehand,  and then write down the results.